# Numerically estimate $f^{\prime}(\pi/7)$ if $f(x) = \sin(x)$

Tags: calculus

How would I approach this problem? Do I make a table of sin (x) values and then find the mean or is there another way?

Comment: You calculate first $f'(x)$ and then plug in $\pi/7$

Comment: How exactly are you looking to estimate the value? The derivative of sine is cosine, which has a nice Taylor series expansion that you could use to estimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the derivative of sine is cosine.
$$f(x) = \sin(x) \implies f’x = \cos(x)$$
Now, just calculate $f’(\frac{\pi}{7})$.
$$f\big(\frac{\pi}{7}\big) = \cos\big(\frac{\pi}{7}\big) \approx 0.90096886 \approx 0.9$$

Answer (score 1):

May be, one of the problem is to compute exactly the value of $\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right)$. If you look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi7.html), you will see that this is a root of the equation
$$8x^3-4x^2-4x+1=0$$

Using Cardano method, you have three roots since $\Delta=3136$ but we face here a *casus irreducibilis* where the three roots express with radicals and complex numbers.

So, may the best is to use the Taylor series of the cosine around $x=\frac \pi 6$
$$\cos(x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \left(x-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)-\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{3}
   \left(x-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)^2+\frac{1}{12} \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{6}\right)^3+\frac{1}{16
   \sqrt{3}}\left(x-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)^4+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)^5\right)$$
and get, as an approximation
$$\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{7}\right)\approx \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{\pi }{84}-\frac{\pi ^2}{2352 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{\pi
   ^3}{889056}+\frac{\pi ^4}{49787136 \sqrt{3}}\approx 0.9009688584$$ while the exact value would be $0.9009688679$